# how to avoid null condition in declared variable in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
CREATE TABLE #UserCompany
    ([ID] int, [CustId] varchar(2), [CustName] varchar(1), [Status] int)
;

INSERT INTO #UserCompany
    ([ID], [CustId], [CustName], [Status])
VALUES
    (1, 'a1', 'A', null),
    (2, 'a1', 'A', null),
    (3, 'a2', 'B', null),
    (4, 'a3', 'B', null),
    (5, 'a4', 'C', null),
    (6, 'a4', 'C', null),
    (7, 'a4', 'D', null),
    (8, 'a6', 'E', null)
;select * from #UserCompany
```

while passing some value iam getting values

```
declare @id varchar(100)='1,2'
select * from #UserCompany where id in (select  CAST(value AS int)  FROM string_SPLIT(@id, ','))
```

if iam passing null iam not getting any value how to retrieve even we dont pass anything as like below

```
declare @id varchar(100)=null
select * from #UserCompany where id in (select  CAST(value AS int)  FROM string_SPLIT(@id, ','))
```

output should be total table should display

Comment: `... or @id is NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @id varchar(100)='1,2'

select * 
from #UserCompany 
where id in (select  CAST(value AS int)  FROM string_SPLIT(@id, ','))
   OR @id IS NULL;
```